# Store token without regenerate every request - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, access-token

I have `API 1` and `API 2`

`API 2` required the token, with I will get the token from the `Identity` and sent it to `API 2`

But the problem now, I don't have idea where to store the token in `API 1`. So temporary solution is I keep request the token every time when sent request to `API 2`.

The token got the expired time, if already expired then generate new token

It can be done?

My snippet code

```
  var pairs = new List < KeyValuePair < string,
  string >> {
   new KeyValuePair < string,
   string > ("client_id", "spa"),
   new KeyValuePair < string,
   string > ("client_secret", "secretkey"),
   new KeyValuePair < string,
   string > ("grant_type", "password"),
   new KeyValuePair < string,
   string > ("username", "test@test"),
   new KeyValuePair < string,
   string > ("Password", "test1234")


  };
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

 using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
  var response = client.PostAsync("https://myidentity.com/" + "connect/token", content).Result;
  var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

  var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Token > (result);

  //Sent request to API 2
 }
```

My token class

```
public class Token
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public string issued { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public string expires { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend use ADAL (Azure Active Directory Library) from Microsoft which cache the token by default . when you call AcquireTokenSilentAsync it looks for token in the cache first.  You can find more about here https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token

Comment: To really do it properbly, you need multiple things: 1st: don't do `new HttpClient()`. Use the new `HttpClientFactory`. See here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore. With that out of the way, you can cache the token and try to use it from the cache. If the request fails, you get another one and retry. The easiest way is to use the InMemoryCache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Also (more advanced) you can combine all this token caching/renovation by implementing a custom DelegateHandler: See also here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers